# Starting point function and finishing point function of a Omnet++ simulation

Tags: omnet++

In general, when a simulation (with a network and number of modules) is run in the Omnet++, what function is the starting point of that simulation? Also, what function is the end point of simulation?
For example, I want to add the following command in the starting function body:

```
EV << "The simulation is started";
```

and the following command in the finishing function body:

```
EV << "The simulation is finished";
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is `initialize()` and `finish()`.

If you need global callbacks then the `cISimulationLifecycleListener` might be more appropriate. See in the [manual](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:plugin-exts:simulation-lifetime-listeners).

Comment: I am looking for them, but above and independent of any module within the network. In other words, I right-click on omnetpp.ini and then click on the menu items "Run As/1 Omnet++ Simulation" that appear, in general, what function is executed first, and which function is executed as the last function when the simulation is finished?

Comment: OMNeT++ is a C++ program. Once you click the RunAs, `main()` is the first (and last) function that is executed which is situated in the `opp_run` command. But that is not designed to be modified by the model developer. For the model's purposes the cISimulationLifecycleListener should be used.

Comment: I want to for a project, not all projects. Is it possible to override on the cISimulationLifecycleListener in the project I want?